# google maps api v3 : displaying info on marker load

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

is it possible to display a marker with info associated loaded at marker load?

I want, on zoom change, display some markers on the map with a number associated. The number is the result of a query via ajax. (ex. the number of partners for a project)

here is the code i've tried:

```
var markerSardegna = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.184302, 9.153784),
    map: newmap
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerSardegna, 'load', function (event) {
    var prova = event;
    showMarkerInfo(prova, newmap, 'Italy', 7);
});
```

Comment: Possible?? I'm sure it is, but this isn't "you ask & we do", don't you think? Have you some code?

Comment: Sorry... here is the code i've tried:

`var markerSardegna = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.184302,9.153784),
    map: newmap
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerSardegna, 'load', function(event) {
    var prova = event;
    showMarkerInfo(prova, newmap, 'Italy',7);
});`

Comment: Don't add your code as a comment to your question. Simply update your question to include that code.  It'll be a lot easier to read!  I'll do it for you this time :-)